# How to get JSON value based on other JSON values

Tags: json, xml, go

I have a struct in Go that came from and XML resp body:

```
{ 
    "pdp":{
        "sellableUnits":[
            {
                "attributes":[
                    {
                        "id":"22555278",
                        "type":"size",
                        "value":"03.5"
                    }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}


type sizeJ struct {
    PDP struct {
        SellableUnits []struct {
            Attributes []struct {
                ID    string `json:"id"`
                Type  string `json:"type"`
                Val string `json:"value"`
            } `json:"attributes"`
        } `json:"units"`
    } `json:"pdp"`
}
```

There are different Vals and a different ID depending on the value of Val.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`for`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) loop, with `range` if you like.

```golang
func getValByID(j sizeJ, id string) string {
    for _, u := range j.PDP.SellableUnits {
        for _, a := range u.Attributes {
            if a.ID == id {
                return a.Val
            }
        }
    }
    return ""
}

func getIDByVal(j sizeJ, val string) string {
    for _, u := range j.PDP.SellableUnits {
        for _, a := range u.Attributes {
            if a.Val == val {
                return a.ID
            }
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/LjPrs1yGKGc

Comment: Why would I be getting a blank output when running this?

Comment: @SalvatoreTimpani Because the input you're providing is either empty or incorrect. You can see in the link that this approach works.

Comment: There is nothing wrong, my input matches what is between the <id> tags

Comment: @SalvatoreTimpani Look, no one can debug what they can't see. There's no `<id>` tag in the question. The solution in the link works with a dummy json because you didn't provide one. If your data is different why don't you just include it in the question?

Comment: added above just now

Comment: The `json` tags in the struct *must* match the json fields. In your question you have `json:"units"` in the struct but in the json you have `"sellableUnits"`. Update accordingly and it will work: https://play.golang.org/p/tgwgjq_0IpL

Comment: @SalvatoreTimpani so you're saying that if you click `Run` in the linked example it does not work?

Comment: @SalvatoreTimpani can you define what "does work" would look like? Put your code that does not work into an executable, testable form, preferably on https://play.golang.org/ and share it.

Comment: So in your mind "03.5" is the same as "5.000000"? I'm not sure I can help with that.

Comment: There are many sets of those attributes, if you use 03.5 it will not work either

Comment: by printing the result of `floatToString`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225964/discussion-between-salvatore-timpani-and-mkopriva).

Comment: Your original question is about how to retrieve the value based on the id, if you pass the correct value you get the id. However you're using `floatToString` which produces values very different from those that are stored in the json/struct. Your problem now is not about how to get the id, but how to properly format a `float64` value to a `string` that matches some arbitrary json.

Comment: Even if using a hard coded string of "05.5" same thing

Comment: or "05.0" same thing or "03.5"

Comment: The json contains `"03.5"` and with that it works just fine: https://play.golang.org/p/8l_HxGzj1cl.

Answer (score 0):

you can use map instead of nested struct,such as

```
var myMap map[string]map[string]interface{}
```

or

```
var myMap map[string]interface{}
```

or every thing you want.

Comment: ok but when I use this sctruct on a resp body how would I log the ID based on the Val ?